# Callback to constructor with multiple parameters

Tags: class, parameters, constructor, callback, kotlin

What I've tried so far is callback with single parameter and it works:

```
class SomeClass (something:Int = 3, val callback: (Int) -> Unit) {
    fun doSomething() {
      callback(11)
    }
}

class AnotherClass {

    val something = SomeClass({onSomething(it)}) 

    protected fun onSomething(num: Int) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But how to implemented it with multiple parameters like:

```
class SomeClass (something:Int = 3, val callback: (Int, String) -> Unit) {
    fun doSomething() {
      callback(11, "Yeah")
    }
}

class AnotherClass {

    val something = SomeClass(/* ...... what goes here???? */) 

    protected fun onSomething(num: Int, str: String) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the [lambda expression syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expression-syntax) with explicit parameters:

```
val something = SomeClass { num, str -> onSomething(num, str) }
```

<sup>When passing a lambda as the last parameter, you can omit the parenthesis.</sup>

Also, you can use a [bound function reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references) when the expected and actual function signatures match exactly:

```
val something = SomeClass(this::onSomething)
```